# Get Facebook persistent stream key from Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-php-sdk

I can obtain a Facebook stream key through the graph API.
I saw there's an option to make the Facebook stream key persistent with updating the video ID `persistent_stream_key_status` but when I used this option, I got the following error:

```
No permission to use persistent stream key param
```

The Facebook permission that I used is `publish_video` for publishing videos directly to the user page.

I don't know what permission Facebook has to add a persistent stream key parameter. Does anyone know?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I am getting the same error when I try to enable the persistent stream key on an existing stream.

Comment: Still figure out this problem. I'm still trying make verification fb app. But until now still unverified. Fb verification is to slow